# Interpereting dsolve output to use with ODE45 [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, dsolve

i've been trying to solve a second order differential equation using this [1](http://12000.org/my_notes/matlab_ODE/),
however I couldnt get it right and found nothing helpful online but I believe I've made progress.

I used *dsolve*;

```
syms x(t) v(t) fi(t)

[x(t), v(t)] = dsolve(diff(x) == v, diff(v) == fi/m, x(0) == [-L, -L], v(0) == [5, 10] )
```

which gives me;

```
   x(t) =



int(fi(x)/5, x, 0, t, 'IgnoreSpecialCases', true, 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true) - 5





v(t) =

C2 + t*(int(fi(x)/5, x, 0, t, 'IgnoreSpecialCases', true, 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true) - 5) + int(-(x*fi(x))/5, x, 0, t, 'IgnoreSpecialCases', true, 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true)
```

Now I need help interperating the result and I wonder if I can use this result to get something out of ode45? Also I want to plot the solution as a reference trajectory to a simulation of 500 particles moving through a forcefield.

---

using ODE45:

```
function dxdt = solution(t,y0)
frprintf('Second stop')
.....
dxdt = [x, v]
end
```

call from main file:

```
t:dt:t_f
y0 = [x0,v0]
fprintf('first stop')
[x, v] = ode45(@solution, y0, t)
```

I've set it up so that if the code would run smoothly it would print "first stop, second stop, third stop" and "fourth stop", it only prints out first stop and thats where I get the error.

Comment: `dsolve` and `int` are for symbolic math and designed mainly to obtain analytical solutions. `ode45` is used to solve ODEs numerically. These two things are very different from each other. Your symbolic equations here are completely abstract so you shouldn't expect any solutions. I recommend that you go back to learning how to use `ode45`. Read the documentation (`doc ode45` in your Command Window). Try the examples. Don't expect to figure it out right away. If you come across issues/questions, search this site. If you ask a question, make sure that it is specific.

Comment: So I can't really put anything that comes out of this into ode45?

Comment: No. I don't see the point. `dsolve` is meant to give you an analytic solution to a differential equation *if one exists*. It can't exist here, because you've specified everything in terms of an abstract function (a function without a definition) `fi`. If you want to use symbolic math to help you derive the functions for `ode45`, [see this MathWorks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from-symbolic-differential-equations-to-their-numeric-solution/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you somewhere defined

```
function F = fi(t)
    F = ...
end
```

you define the ODE function as (using `m` as global variable)

```
function doty = odefunc(t,y)
    doty = [ y(2); fi(t)/m ]
end
```

and call

```
t = t0:dt:tf
y0 = [ x0, v0 ]
t,y = ode45(odefunc, t, y0)

plot( t, y(:,1) )
```

---

Generally, the vector `y` would contain a point in the phase space (position and velocity/impulse) for all particles or objects in the system. In `odefunc` you would then compute the forces for this particular phase space point at the time `t` and compose from that the derivative vector to the phase space point.

In a 3D simulation you, for instance, could arrange that `y(6*(k-1)+1:6*(k-1)+3)` are the position of particle `k` and `y(6*(k-1)+4:6*(k-1)+6)` the velocity vector. Or you could separate position and velocity with `y(3*(k-1)+1:3*(k-1)+3)` for position and `y(3*(N+k-1)+1:3*(N+k-1)+3)` for the velocity for the `k`-th of `N` particles.

Comment: Okay, so lets get this straight;
I have my script-file wherein I run the simulation and calculate the force on each particle for each time step, therefore there's not function for F, just the some lines where I compute it.

in your second example, is that all there is to that function?
and as for calling it, I do that from my main scriptfile, yes?

Comment: No, you need to be able to compute the force for each point of the phase space of the system. The ensuing derivative vector is what is computed in odefunc. And yes, the call to `ode45` is closer to main in the call hierarchy than `odefunc`. Or contained in the main file. You are aware that you can have multiple `function ... end` blocks in one file, naming and top function are only important for the automatic loading of the file.

Comment: Still facing some problems with this; I make this call:
`t = 0:0.001:t_f;
x0 = [-5, -5];
v0 = [5, 10];

U = [x0,v0];
S = ode45(odefunc, t, U);'

'plot(t,S(:,1),'g.')
xlabel('t');
ylabel('x');`

to this function:

`function dxdt = odefunc(t,x)
        m = 1;
        dxdt_1 = fi;
        dxdt_2 = v0 + (t/m)*fi;
        
        dxdt = [dxdt_1; dxdt_2];
    end`

and it says "Undefined function or
variable 'odefunc'." 
:/

Comment: Perhaps you need to give it as `@odefunc`. However, there may be an error while interpreting `odefunc`. Also, you get `dxdt_x = v` and `dxdt_v = fi/m`, there is no `v0` in `odefunc`. Take care for compatible matrix formats.

Comment: I added the `@` but just got another error; Error using feval
`Undefined function
'solution' for input
arguments of type
'double'.

Error in odearguments
(line 87)
f0 =
feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});
% ODE15I sets args{1}
to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line
113)
[neq, tspan, ntspan,
next, t0, tfinal,
tdir, y0, f0,
odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in lab1script2d
(line 119)
[x,v] =
ode45(@solution, t,
y0); `

Comment: Could you please add the current state of the use of ODE45 resp. ODE15 to the question (using a simplified minimal example with the same errors) or open a new question for it? There are lots of details missing, small errors should not produce internal error messages of the matlab procedures.

Comment: I extended the preexisting question

Comment: Can you get the examples of https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html to work, either by copying them into one file per function or into a single file? Can you reproduce your error with these examples, can you solve it by rearranging the order of the functions?

Comment: I got it to work now; I renamed the .m-file which contains the function